# Accessing Hive queries from Jenkins

Tags: hadoop, jenkins, hive

I am planning to use Jenkins with Hive. I have created some Hive scripts: test1.hql, test2.hql, test3.hql which lie on the sample server "ssh rt@test1.test2.net" location "/home/rt"

```
test1.hql:
select id, name from tblA;

test2.hql:
select id, name from tblB;

test3.hql:
select id, name from tblC;
```

How can I execute it from Jenkins?

On Jenkins up-to below is what I did:

New Job > Job name as test > Build a free-style software project

How can I point to my .hql scripts from Jenkins and what settings do I need to have? I am new to Jenkins.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: You could execute shell scripts from jenkins and from within those shell scripts call the hql using "hive -f". Not sure if it is the best way.

Comment: can you show me how? explain a little bit. where to put what script?

Comment: Sorry dont have access to a jenkins environment right now.

Answer (score 0):

Found something:

Create a Jenkins job
In the configuration of that job there is a "Build" section with "Add build step" 
Add a "Execute Shell" step, and  put your code.

that code would be basically:
hive -f /pathtohql/test1.hql

The only issue i see with this is that the m/c with jenkins will have to have hive installed and pointing to the correct metastore & cluster.